# Laravel Call to a member function on a non-object

Tags: php, oop, laravel

I have searched on stack and found many questions like this...

However, I am sure that I am using an object and have verified that in the dump.

**Error**

`>16: Call to a member function getRealPath() on a non-object`

**Line 16**

`$image->getRealPath();`

**Var Dump $image**

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)#9 (7) { ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> bool(false) ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> string(41) "5a862f92da957da3e0208357ce006afd_970x.jpg" ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> int(346047) ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> int(0) ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpA5C7.tmp" ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(11) "phpA5C7.tmp" }
```

If I dump `$image->getRealPath();` I get a `string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpE193.tmp"` which is what I want.  I have no idea why it's saying $image is not an object when clearly it is.

**Controller**

```
# Process Images - Queue?
if ($filesUploaded) {
    $images = Input::file('images');
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        # Record Creation
        $record = new Image;
        $record->user_id = Auth::id();
        $record->ad_id = $adId;
        $record->name = Str::random();
        $record->save();
        # Create TN
        $record->createTN($image);
        # Create Smalls
        # Create Larges
    }
}
```

**Image class**

```
public function createTN($image) {
    $PUBLIC_PATH = public_path();

# Load Zebra Image Library
require_once $PUBLIC_PATH.'/uploads/Zebra_Image.php';

$destinationPath = $PUBLIC_PATH.'/uploads/thumbnails/';
$tn = new Zebra_Image();
$tn->source_path = $image->getRealPath();
$tn->target_path = $destinationPath.$this->name.'_sm.jpg';
$tn->jpeg_quality = 60;
$tn->preserve_aspect_ratio = true;
$tn->enlarge_smaller_images = true;
$tn->resize(100, 100, ZEBRA_IMAGE_CROP_CENTER);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your full code please?

Comment: If you do a `dd($image)` inside the `createTN($image)` function what do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the original loop

```
$images = Input::file('images');
foreach ($images as $image) {
    # Record Creation
    $record = new Image;
    $record->user_id = Auth::id();
    $record->ad_id = $adId;
    $record->name = Str::random();
    $record->save();
    # Create TN
    $record->createTN($image);
    # Create Smalls
    # Create Larges
}
```

It looks like you're processing a request with more than a single file upload.  The form, javascript code, or flash uploader code you're using to post to this Laravel route looks like it's sending at least one file (or perhaps a blank file entry) that Laravel's request object can't process into an object.  A loop like this might reveal more about what's going on

```
foreach($images as $image)
{
    var_dump($image);
}
```

Most of those will be `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile` objects, but I bet at least one of them is a `null`.  You could also try `var_dump($_FILES)` and look for any obvious errors or empty entries -- maybe something that's too large for the server to process?

The reason you couldn't use [lukasgeiter's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1903366/lukasgeiter) solution is the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile` class has PHP's internal `SplFileInfo` class as an ancsetor, and until [very recently](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65213) PHP had a bug/feature where a programmer couldn't cast `SplFileInfo` as a boolean (using the using `!` converts the variable to a boolean type for the comparision)

Finally, Laravel relies on Symfony components for its file upload functionality.  I believe you can find the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile` instantiations here

```
#File: vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/FileBag.php
protected function convertFileInformation($file)
{
    if ($file instanceof UploadedFile) {
        return $file;
    }

    $file = $this->fixPhpFilesArray($file);
    if (is_array($file)) {
        $keys = array_keys($file);
        sort($keys);

        if ($keys == self::$fileKeys) {
            if (UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE == $file['error']) {
                $file = null;
            } else {
                $file = new UploadedFile($file['tmp_name'], $file['name'], $file['type'], $file['size'], $file['error']);
            }
        } else {
            $file = array_map(array($this, 'convertFileInformation'), $file);
        }
    }

    return $file;
}
```

So if you're a debug at the source sort of person, start here.

Answer (score 2):

One of your images probably is not set. So when you check (the first) with a `var_dump` everything seems alright. But when the full loop runs it throws an exception on the second, third, ... iteration.

This should fix it:

```
foreach ($images as $image) {
    if(!is_object($image)) continue;
    # Record Creation
    $record = new Image;
    $record->user_id = Auth::id();
    $record->ad_id = $adId;
    $record->name = Str::random();
    $record->save();
    # Create TN
    $record->createTN($image);
    # Create Smalls
    # Create Larges
}
```

Comment: Tried that but received `Object of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile could not be converted to boolean `

Comment: @Rafael Try if(!is_object($image)) { continue; } instead.

Comment: @AlanStorm Thank you it worked without errors.  Can you please explain to me what happened?  I really don't know why it didn't work with my code.